# How to using replace function in tdengine through sql

Tags: tdengine

I have used tdengine for a few weeks, I know that tdengine has some basic methods that are helpful.
But I meet a problem while using sql to query data from tdengine, and I want to some column edit for the retrieve columns. In mysql the sql would like this :

```
SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
```

I didn't find any method like this for tdnengine. And i want to ask does tdengine support this function or not? if not does tdengine support udf that i can define a replace function by myself?

Answer (score 0):

TDengine doesn't support "Seelct Replace()", we have plan to support UDF in near future, but there isn't specific target date for releasing UDF for now.